# AngularJS Uncaught ReferenceError: ng-repeat ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do not know why an error. 
When you run the ng-click in the ng-repaet, Uncaught ReferenceError occurs. 
Are you sure you will not know the cause of the click event does not occur?

test.js

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.add = function() {
        alert("add click");
    };

    $scope.list = function() {
        return [{"1": {id: 1, name: "aaa"},
                "2": {id: 2, name: "bbb"},
                "3": {id: 3, name: "ccc"}}];
    }
}]);
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table class="table table-striped" ng-init="list = list()">
            <tr ng-repeat="element in list">
                <td ng-repeat="nake in element" onclick="add()">{{nake.id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined
```

Comment: Use `ng-click` instead of `onclick` , like: `ng-click="add()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ng-click` angular tag, like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="nake in element" ng-click="add(nake.name)">{{nake.id}}</td>
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kutyel/0h3rnne1/)** to see that it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ng-click` directive instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click instead of onclick since any function binded to scope cannot be accessed through onclick event.

```
<td ng-repeat="nake in element" ng-click="add()">
```